# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sceneform

Need Help to solve this nullpointerexception error!
I've put a comment in Capital letters before the line at which I'm getting this error.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) 

            View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_object_placer, container, false);

            //Fetchting the instance of arFragment ID in XML
            arFragment = (ArFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);



    >NEXT LINE IS GIVING THE ERROR 

         arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {
            //TRIED TO RUN CODE COMMENTING CODE BELOW STILL STILL GETIING ERROR AT ABOVE LINE
            //Crating an Anchor on location where user has tapped
//             Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
//             ModelRenderable.builder()
//                    .setSource(getActivity(), Uri.parse(s))
//                    .build()
//                    .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addModelToScene(anchor, modelRenderable ));
            }));



        return view;

    }
```

> Java null pointer exception
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'void com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment$OnTapArPlaneListener)'
> on a null object reference
> at com.example.augmentedreality.Modules.ObjectPlacer.ObjectPlacer.onCreateView(ObjectPlacer.java:55)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
> at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

Answer (score 0):

TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE USE CHILDFRAGMENT MANAGER

```
//Fetchting the instance of arFragment ID in XML
            arFragment = (ArFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
```